# CSS vertical column styling

Tags: php, html, css

So i am trying to create a simple grid. Here's my CSS styling for the page:

```
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    }


.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:5px 5px;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: gainsboro;}

.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:5px 5px;
    border-width:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:right;}

.occu {border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;}

.occu th {
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal; 
    height:500px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    bottom: 2px;
    vertical-align:bottom;}

.occu th > div { transform: rotate(270deg);
width:20px;
    text-align:left;}

.occu th > div > span { border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;padding: 5px 10px;  }
```

I have a separate class for the column header because that is the only way I could align the Column names as how I wanted them to be.This is how it looks

[image]

What I am trying to do now is resize the column width by retrieving a value for each column from the db. I was able to do this for the rows but not the columns. This is how it looks even if I manually try to resize the column with in css.

[image]

Part of the writing gets chipped off and I don't know why. Nothing seems to work.
Can someone please help me out?

Comment: What error? What does your code look like? What does the data that you're actually using look like?

Comment: Not sure I follow you, here. Are columns getting larger once cells are populated?

Comment: There is no error. But as you can see from the second image the vertical column names are getting chipped off. 
The columns are getting larger in a random order and it won't take in the size I give.